# Replacing string in a file with another string

Tags: java, file, replace

What is the fastest way to do a search and replace on a string in an existing file using Java?

Let's say I have this:

```
// This references an existing file 
File file = ...
```

The file in question looks like this:

```
The Green Dog is furry.
It likes to run in the Green Grass.
Green is its favorite color.
```

How would I go about replacing the String "Green" with "Blue" and having that file re-saved with the new color?

**Update:**
I've thought about this a little more and perhaps the best and fastest way is to just read the contents of the file into a string (using something like FileUtils) and then just doing a replace and re-writing to the file?

Comment: Not the same answer, but close http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939561/how-can-this-java-code-be-improved-to-find-sub-string-in-a-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Retrieving and Replacing number in text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990036/retrieving-and-replacing-number-in-text-file) which is pretty much the same.

Edit: Regarding your update, I would just use BufferedReader and BufferedWriter and leave it to the JVM to optimise reads/writes, i.e. I would do the replacements in a streaming fashion. Your suggested solution of reading to memory could be a bit faster - but I wouldn't read everything in memory (makes approach not scalable) unless there's a very good reason.